# disassociate input from parent form

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Is it possible to completely disassociate an `<input>` element from its parent form? I have a situation where I have to use an `<input>` element for a text input but I don't want it to be a part of the form. I know leaving the `name` attribute blank effectively hides the field *most* of the time but, for example, I have code the loops over the `form.elements` collection which *does* include unnamed fields. I don't want to have to filter the `elements` list.

I tried emulating `<input>` behavior in an editable div but the implementation became fairly complex (handling copy/paste, formatting, line breaks). It looks like the `form` attribute might help but I want to support IE10+.

I want the `<input>` behavior without including it in any of its parents' form submittal or form element querying methods.

Edit: To clarify, I'm mostly concerned with removing the `<input>` from the `form.elements` collection. Even if the element is unnamed, it still appears in that list.

Edit 2: I can't simply move the elements to another div since they physically appear in the form and flow with the rest of the content.

Form submittal event handlers are unhelpful since they don't apply to the `form.elements` collection.

Comment: Please share the code what you have tried

Comment: Your question is totally unclear.

Comment: could you please share the HTML and JS code, so we can see your loop and have a better understanding of your problem. you could leave the `<input>` outside the form and position it with css where you need it. also you could insert the object into the DOM only when you need it...

Comment: There's not really any code to share. The question is essentially: Can I remove an element from the `form.elements` collection.

Comment: I can't reposition the element with CSS as it has to flow with other form elements.

Comment: @BrinMarx my answer would be, the form is part of the DOM, so you can manipulate its content. give the form an id and use it to point to its children elements...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I came up with a suitable solution. It feels a little hacky (read: really hacky) but accomplishes what I need it to do. If anyone has any better ideas let me know.

If I wrap the input in an iframe it's effectively hidden from the form. Unfortunatly, I don't think I can directly append the input to the child document so it needs to be cloned by hand. Here's my quick and dirty proof of concept code:

```
<style>
    iframe {
        border: 0;
        width: 100%;
    }
</style>
<form id="myForm">
    <input style="width: 100%"/>
</form>
<script>
    (function() {
        var myForm = document.getElementById("myForm");
        console.log(myForm.elements.length);
        var input = myForm.querySelector("input");
        input.parentElement.removeChild(input)
        var frame = myForm.appendChild(document.createElement("iframe"));
        var frameInput = frame.contentDocument.querySelector("body").appendChild(frame.contentDocument.createElement("input"));
        frameInput.setAttribute("style", input.getAttribute("style"));
        console.log(myForm.elements.length);
        frameInput.addEventListener("click", externalListener);
    })();

    function externalListener() {
        alert();
    }
</script>
```

This shows that the parent form no longer sees the input and that the parent document can still listen to events fired from within the iframe.

Answer (score 2):

Iterate the form and find all the inputs. Clone each input and append it somewhere say a `<div>`(if you still want to keep the inputs) and then remove the input using `.remove()` method.

```js
$('form :input').each(function(){
  $input=$(this).clone(true);
  $('#container').append($input).append('<br>');
  $(this).remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  Inside Form
  <input type="text" id="txt1" name="txt1" value="txt1"><br>
  <input type="text" id="txt2" name="txt2" value="txt2">
</form>
<br>
<br>
<div id="container">
  Inside Div <br>
</div>
```

Comment: This interrupts the document flow. I need the elements to remain in their correct positions.

Comment: The `<inputs>` are physically part of the form and the document flow. If I move them to an external div there's no way to return them to their previous positions (easily)

Answer (score 1):

You could put a "container" element (like a `div`) at the place where you want the input to appear (within a `form`) , but put the actual `input` element outside of the form, so it is not a descendant of it in the DOM tree.

Then on page load, and on every resize of the window, move the `input` (which has an `absolute` position style) on top of the container, without altering its location in the DOM tree:

```js
function positionInput() {
    var myinput = document.querySelector('#myinput');
    // give input same size as container element
    var container = document.querySelector('#container');
    myinput.style.height = container.offsetHeight + 'px'; 
    myinput.style.width = container.offsetWidth + 'px';
    // move input element to the container location
    myinput.style.top = container.offsetTop + 'px';
    myinput.style.left = container.offsetLeft + 'px';
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', positionInput);
window.addEventListener('resize', positionInput);
```

```html
<input id="myinput" style="position:absolute" value="hello">
<h1>Title of form</h1>
<form style="margin: 10px">
    <div id="container" style="background: yellow">&nbsp;</div>
</form>
```

Note that I gave the container a yellow background just to demonstrate it is completely covered by the moved `input` element.

In the above code, the resize event is captured to reallign the `input` with the potentially new position and size of the container. You could extend this, so this reallignment is also performed when other events occur, or even at set intervals (with `setInterval`).

Comment: While this is a good solution for a statically positioned and sized form, I want to preserve the "stretchiness" of these fields.

Comment: What do you mean with the stretchiness of an `input` field? By default it is fixed in size, whatever happens to its container?

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant I need the ability to use `width: 100%` or similar which resizes it based on the regular document flow.

Comment: I updated my answer accordingly. Now a `100%` sized "container" div can be used. The `input` will follow the reflowed position on every window resize event. Other events could be captured to do the same, as necessary.